# Yocto image cant detect usbs on Raspberry Pi 4

Tags: image, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, yocto, raspberry-pi4

For some reason my Raspberry pi 4, which has mounted a Yocto (Zeus) image cannot detect any usbs inserted into any of it's ports.

This was not the case with the Raspberry pi 3, which would automatically detect any usbs inserted and automatically mount them.

I'm using the same image on both Pis.

The images run fine on both Raspberry Pi versions, it's just the Raspberry Pi 4 cannot detect any usbs inserted.

Note that in order to get the image working on Raspberry Pi 4, I've had to copy and paste over eight elf files from the default Raspbian image.

I've tried changing the config.txt file for the image, but nothing I've changed seems to have any effect on the Raspberry Pi 4 detecting usbs inserted.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.